# How to eliminate old Ubuntu Boot option

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu on a live USB stick and I used this just to explore ubuntu. When I start up my computer (HP Envy 15 w/Windows 7) it still gives me the option to start up with Windows 7 or Ubuntu. The Ubuntu option never worked for me so I uninstalled ubuntu from the USB drive. How do I get rid of the boot option for ubuntu? I can't get rid of it, and even though I don't have ubuntu on this computer anymore, it still offers to boot with it.

How do I get rid of this? How to completely get rid of all Ubuntu files on this computer? (I now have another computer which I only use Ubuntu on).

Thanks.

Comment: You have installed Ubuntu on the hard drive, or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

Try following this link. I used it to delete mine.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17903/remove-ubuntu-or-xp-from-the-windows-7-boot-menu/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.